# MySql foreign key which is a composite key - what is the syntax?

Tags: sql, mysql, foreign-keys

Is it possible to have a composite key in mysql(5.1) and if so, what is the syntax?
table a:
column aa,bb

references table b
columns b_aa,b_bb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With InnoDB tables, you can, like:

```
create table YourTable (
     col1 int, 
     col2 int, 
     constraint foreign key (col1, col2) 
                references OtherTable (col1, col2) 
                on delete cascade
) type=InnoDB;
```

For `MyISAM` tables, foreign key constraint are silently ignored.

[for complete tutorial: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)

Comment: As a side note, InnoDB doesn't understand things like `col1 int references OtherTable (col1)`... it has to be a separate constraint like done above even for single column foreign keys.

Comment: @R. Bemrose: Even worse, MySQL will silently ignore incorrect ways to write a foreign key, making you think you actually created one...